# What is the most accurate snow report website?

Tags: usa, online-resources, weather-and-climate, winter-sports, snow

It's time to ski. But where to go? Where is the snow?

What website or resource is most helpful in finding snow stats such as base depth, conditions, and predicted future conditions?

I am most interested in stats for US resorts (resorts in California, Utah & Colorado, also, New York & Vermont), but would be interested in resources that provide worldwide snow statistics, as well.

Comment: Hi, any state in particular? Might be that we find one for a specific region, for example.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to find worldwide accurate snow reports. This is a very complex field, and to do it accurately, institutes have to focus on one country at most.

Comment: Hi @MarkMayo & RoflcoptrException - Mostly curious about resorts in California, Colorado & Utah (the Mountain West) but also about resorts in the East, ie. Vermont & New York. I edited the question with these specifications.

Answer (score 6):

If all you're concerned about is snow.  You can take a look at:

- [Intellicast](http://www.intellicast.com/Travel/Weather/Snow/Cover.aspx)
- [Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/US/Region/US/2xSnowDepth.html)
- [NOAA Snow Analysis](http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/nsa/)
- [NASA](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/GlobalMaps/view.php?d1=MOD10C1_M_SNOW)

But you really should pick the locations to ski and then look at specific mountains or areas to see what the snow report actually says.

**EDIT**

OK.  Here is the resource specifically for the SKI resorts in the US and not only there.

[On The Snow](http://www.onthesnow.com/)

Comment: Thx Karlson, these are helpful resources. But none seem to include readily accessible data (historical, or otherwise) on specific resorts & ski areas. Lemme know if you come across any other helpful sites.

Answer (score 5):

We've had good luck in Colorado resorts with Joel Gratz at http://opensnow.com/ He posts detailed ski forecasts in addition to accumulation reports. There are 4 other reporters on the site for other US ski areas.